# Inject servlet request to to controller in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring boot app , that listen to  a PUT requests . 
My server consume  octant-stream header , 
And my method signature is  (File file) and has request param ... 
When I test my resource from postman , 
The url looks like this : 
:\test.txt
Header : application octant-stream

I would like to know how to pass the file with in the request ... is there any option to inject the servlet request to the controller ? 
So my url will look like : 
 server.com/upload
Header : application octant-stream

I hope my question makes sense .. 
thank you For your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring `MultipartFile` to get the uploded file from the `RequestParam`.

Answer (score 0):

I have passed in the method signature : HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest and it works fine .